# youtube-dl how to set limit of download time

Tags: python, youtube-dl

im using python to check if certain channel is live or not by using "https://www.youtube.com/channel/channel_id/live"
by using youtube dl "is_live" I have managed to get what I want.

However, if the channel is not streaming, it takes ages to download the whole channel including all the playlist.

I want to stop the download if download time excess 5 seconds. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Does this help? : https://www.mankier.com/1/youtube-dl#--socket-timeout

Comment: you can add `{socket_timeout: 5}` as `ydl_opts` in the instance by `ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)` where 5 is seconds

Comment: @mama I tried socket timeout but it doesn't work. I guess it only work when its bringing calling the page

Comment: I'd go with thread termination rather than a subprocess, myself, but we have answers in the knowledge base showing both approaches.

Answer (score 0):

You could add your code in the download function of this template:

```py
import asyncio

async def download(url):
    await asyncio.sleep(3600)
    print(url)

async def youtbe(url):
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(download(url), timeout=5.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print(f'timeout on {url}')



async def main(urls):
    await asyncio.gather(*[youtbe(url) for url in urls])

urls = [
        'hej00',
        'hej01',
        'hej02',
        'hej03',
        'hej04',
        'hej05',
        'hej06',
        'hej07',
        'hej08',
        'hej09',
        'hej10',
        ]
asyncio.run(main(urls))
```

The 5 seconds timeout is defined in the `wait_for` function from `asyncio`